# How to ssign Variable with div element's name

Tags: javascript, variables, getelementsbyname

So I got multiple divs with different images embedded. Each one has its unique name attributes. I'm trying to apply the hover effect to each divs by changing the image source. I don't want to write multiple scripts, rather I'm trying to write a just one block of script that would effect every div.

```
<div id="div1" >
    <img id="img1" name="img1" src="img1_up.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <img id="img2" name="img2" src="img2_up.jpg" />
</div>...and so on
```

Now here is the script that I currently have for the rollover effects

```
<script>
    var var1 = document.getElementById("div1");
    var1.addEventListener("mouseover", changeImage1);
    var1.addEventListener("mouseout", restoreImage1);

    function changeImage1() {
        document.getElementById("img1").src = "img1_ro.jpg";
    }

    function restoreImage1() {
        document.getElementById("img1").src = "img1_up.jpg";
    }

    var var2 = document.getElementById("div2");
    var2.addEventListener("mouseover", changeImage2);
    var2.addEventListener("mouseout", restoreImage2);

    function changeImage2() {
        document.getElementById("img2").src = "img2_ro.jpg";
    }

    function restoreImage2() {
        document.getElementById("img2").src = "img2_up.jpg";
    }...and so on
</script>
```

I would like to use the name attributes from each images to create dynamic code to apply to all images. Here is what I have in mind but not sure the exact way to write it. PLEASE HELP

```
...
var dynamicVar = ????
dynamicVar.addEventListener("mouseover", changeImage();
dynamicVar.addEventListener("mouseout", restoreImage();
function changeImage() {
    document.getElementById(dynamicVar).src = dynamicVar + "_ro.jpg";
}
function restoreImage() {
    document.getElementById(dynamicVar).src = dynamicVar + "_up.jpg";
}
```

Comment: I would recommend using a class and for that you would use `getElementsByClassName()`, you can also use a for loop to apply the eventlisteners to each one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loop` to add event, don't need to specify id for each div:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {    
    if(inputs[i].id.indexOf('div') >= 0) {
        inputs[i].addEventListener("mouseover", changeImage);
        inputs[i].addEventListener("mouseout", restoreImage);
    }
}
function changeImage(){
    var tmpStr = this.id;
    var divIndex = tmpStr.substring(3, tmpStr.length);
    document.getElementById("img" + divIndex).src = divIndex + "_ro.jpg";
}
function restoreImage(){
    var tmpStr = this.id;
    var divIndex = tmpStr.substring(3, tmpStr.length);
    document.getElementById("img" + divIndex).src = divIndex + "_up.jpg";
}
```

**See on fiddle**: [Link](http://fiddle.jshell.net/xLj7ab8g/)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var parent = document.getElementById("parent");
var childs = parent.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < childs.length; i++) {
    (function () {
        var e = childs[i];
        e.addEventListener("mouseover", function () {
            changeImage(e);
        });
        e.addEventListener("mouseout", function () {
            restoreImage(e);
        });
    }());
}

function changeImage(element) {
    var imgs = element.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        alert(imgs[i].id);
    }
}

function restoreImage(element) {
    var imgs = element.getElementsByTagName('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgs[i].src = img_ro;
    }
}
```

you can check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h5okyf2L/)